# Spyder operating issue

Tags: python, input, spyder

I know this has to be one of the stupidest questions of the week, but I'm new to this... Last week I downloaded and installed python, anaconda, and spyder, but spyder keeps throwing up errors when I try to run this simple program... ( It keeps popping up the Issue reporter "spyder has encountered internal problem!" window?)

```
a=int(input('enter value for a\n:'))
b=4
if a>b:
    print('yes', a, 'is greater than', b)
else:
    print('no', a, 'is not greater than', b)
```

Am I doing something wrong?  I tried running this same program in a browser IDE, and it worked fine?
Any help appreciated, and thank you for your time!
Mitch

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code inside my environment, no problem with it.

How did you install your spyder? I did `conda create -n spyder spyder -c conda-forge`

Reference: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#new-conda-environment

Comment: I downloaded then installed spyder through anaconda navigator... That's how I was told to do it... Where did you type 'conda create -n spyder spyder -c conda-forge'?

Comment: There can be many "silos" of python distribution on, say, your Windows system. It's not easy to locate and identify them, and you may not know which one you are using until you do some digging. Python can only access module installed on its own distribution. Anaconda helps you create these silos easily. `conda` command comes with miniconda, somewhat related to anaconda